# MySQL's count(*) doesn't work properly

Tags: mysql, count

I want to count all rows from the `game_votes` where `g_id` is equal to `14`, it is working almost good, but if there aren't any records with `g_id = 14` it does still show `1` in the `cnt` field.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT
     SUM(vote) as vote,
     COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM (`games`)
LEFT JOIN `game_votes`
ON
     `game_votes`.`g_id` = `games`.`id`
WHERE `games`.`id` = '14'
```

Whats wrong? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting a count of 1 because COUNT(*) essentially counts the number of rows in your result set. Since you're selecting a row out of your games table with an id of 14 and left joining that to the game_votes table, you're going to always have 1 or more rows as long as there exists a game with an id of 14 regardless of whether or not it contains any corresponding votes in your game_votes table. Instead of COUNT(*), try COUNT(`game_votes`.`g_id`). If there are no votes, the g_id field will contain a null value, and COUNT() will not include a null value in its calculation.

Answer (score 2):

Check the result of

```
SELECT *
FROM (`games`)
LEFT JOIN `game_votes`
ON
     `game_votes`.`g_id` = `games`.`id`
WHERE `games`.`id` = '14'
```

and you will see that your using `LEFT JOIN` (instead of `JOIN`) is the cause.

Comment: Yeah, but I'm forced to use the `LEFT JOIN`, because I want to check (in one query) if `game` with `id = 14` really exists in the `games` table, what I'm supposed to do in that case?

Comment: Then Zane Bien's solution is exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(vote) as vote, COUNT(*) as cnt from games,game_votes where game_votes.g_id=games.id and games.id=14;
```

This should work

Comment: Works fine, but I recommend using the JOIN syntax which makes the intent of the query much clearer.

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL `SUM` function requires a `GROUP BY` ... see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Comment: "If you use a group function in a statement containing no GROUP BY clause, it is equivalent to grouping on all rows."